# ASP C# update content

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net

I assume this is a simple question for you. Here we go:

On my .aspx page, I have a label *Label1* and a button *Button1* surrounded by an Update Panel.

A click on the Button invokes the code-behind method that looks as follows:

```
protected void Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ThreadProc("Hello");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ThreadProc("Hello2");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ThreadProc("Hello3");
}
void ThreadProc(string info) {
    Label1.Text = info;
    // UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

What I would like to see is that the Label is updated and displayed (rendered) according to what the code does. So it should **Hello**, **Hello2** for 2 seconds and finally **Hello3** should be displayed.
It appears that only the last **Hello3** is rendered. Can someone explain why this happens and how I can implement my idea?

The overall task I try to accomplish is that a click on the button calls a multithreaded function that queries different pages. Whenever a worker thread returns from his mission, it is supposed to update a gridview with the newly added record. Here, the issue is the same: only after all threads have done their job, the webpart is updated.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Cheers
Christoph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the code is running on the web server, it processes the entire method `Click()` before rendering the final page and sending it to the client's web browser.  Therefore, you only see the final results, which has "Hello3" as the `Label1.Text`.

The effect that Thread.Sleep(2000) has on your code is that the HTTP response from the web server takes 4.x seconds instead of only a fraction of a second if you left it out.

However, if you want to see each update to the `Label1.Text`, you can do that with an asynchronous AJAX call.

- [AJAX Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.
Btw, I implemented my task using essentialObjects ProgressBar + JavaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually what the code does is the following:

- The page is requested
- In the server the Label is updated several times
- The page is served with the last value of the label.

The client only get the last value since the output of this code is just static HTML

What you try to accomplish has to be coded on the client side. You could use javascript to get this kind of things done.